# sudo chown -R $USER:admin /system

Tags: macos, bash, osx-mavericks

Somebody had me do the following command `sudo chown -R $USER:admin /system` which essentially has bricked my MacBook. I am able to log in only to safemode:

[image]

**Can someone please help out of this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Somebody had me do the following command `sudo chown -R $USER:admin
>   /system` which essentially has bricked my MacBook.

Someone told you to do `sudo chown -R $USER:admin /system` And you just did that? 100% nuts.

FWIW, it should be `root:wheel`; at least that is what I know from my local Mac OS X 10.9.3 setup.

If you are on Mac OS X 10.9 then I would recommend you reboot holding down the <kbd>Option</kbd> key and boot from the recovery partition.

Once in there launch the `Disk Utility` and have it repair permissions on your main system hard drive.

Comment: Yeah I was trying to fix a problem. I didn't realize his intent was to be malicious. Never had someone do that before. Sad that people get off on that sort of thing. Thank you. I will follow your advice.

Comment: Yea I'm already reading man pages. Thanks for your help. Bash has been confusing for me. I'm fairly new to it. Didn't realize how that 1 command could cause so much damage. Live and learn.. Will never make that mistake again.

Comment: FWIW, I followed your instructions. Thought everything was working. Tried rebooting after the repairs and all i get is a blank white screen. No bootup. Rebooted back into recovery mode and trying to do a timemachine backup but it seems to hang on searching. If you have any other suggestions, I do appreciate it. Thank you.